# Pug - mixin with conditional .json object

Tags: json, pug, mixins

I'm trying to use a conditional (if exists an object at a external .json), but pug doesn't recognize it.

So, my json file is something like this:

```
{
  "portfolioItems": [object1: {
      objectA { ...
      },
      objectB { ...
      },
      "buttons": [{
        key: value
      }, {
        key: value
      }]
    }, object2: {
      objectA { ...
      },
      objectB { ...
      }], object3: {
      objectA { ...
      },
      objectB { ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I need to create an extra div for "object 1" (buttons).

```
mixin portfolio(css, image, title, description)
    div(class= "item " + css)
        .wrap-img
            img(src= assets + "img/home/" + image)&attributes(attributes)
        .wrap-text
            h3= title
            p= description
            if home.portfolioItems.buttons
                div.buttons
                    each val in home.portfolioItems.buttons
                        a(href= val.link, target="_blank")
                            img(class= val.className, src= assets + "img/stores/" + val.image)

div.portfolio--items
            - var projects = home.portfolioItems;
            each item in projects
                +portfolio(item.class, item.image, item.title[lang], item.description[lang])(alt= item.title[lang], title=item.title[lang])
```

Pug can access to "home.portfolioItems.buttons", but it can't do a conditional inside a mixin? Because I can run it outside (but I don't want it).

Thanks in advance. Sorry any mistake in english. ;)

Comment: Where/how have you defined the 'home' object?

Comment: @sean home is a variable defined in pug/js by me that stores json above. Basically, its a shortcut for 'locals' handled by gulp for the pug task. See this examples links (same flow): https://github.com/joaosaro/staro-webkit/blob/master/src/pug/0-setup/variables.pug, https://github.com/joaosaro/staro-webkit/blob/master/gulpfile.js, https://github.com/joaosaro/staro-webkit/blob/master/src/data/home.json

Comment: Are those square brackets properly placed in the json provided in the body of the question?

Comment: @sean I suppose so. Do you understand the problem? Basically, I can access all object with pug, except inside mixins. So I suppose the problem focus should be inside pug

Comment: Have you tried passing the JSON object into the mixin as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixins have their own scope, so you'll need to pass them in an object.  I'd also recommend a single options object which makes this a lot easier than tracking separate parameters, is order-independent, and is more readable too.

Note that you can call a mixin and span multiple lines with the definition

```
+portfolio({
  "css": "css",
  "image": "image",
  "title": "title",
  "description": "description",
  "items": portfolioItems
})
```

This is what the mixin would look like:

```
mixin portfolio(options)
  div(class= "item " + options.css)
    .wrap-img
      img(src= assets + "img/home/" + options.image)&attributes(options.attributes)
    .wrap-text
      h3= options.title
      p= options.description
      if options.items.buttons
        div.buttons
          each val in options.items.buttons
            a(href= val.link, target="_blank")
              img(class= val.className, src= assets + "img/stores/" + val.image)
```

You could also avoid passing in all the items and pass in the buttons OR an empty array if the buttons property doesn't exist in portfolioItems:

```
+portfolio({
  "css": "css",
  "image": "image",
  "title": "title",
  "description": "description",
  "buttons": portfolioItems.buttons || []
})
```

Which would avoid the need for the conditional test as you're guaranteed at least an empty array in the mixin:

```
mixin portfolio(options)
  div(class= "item " + options.css)
    .wrap-img
      img(src= assets + "img/home/" + options.image)&attributes(options.attributes)
    .wrap-text
      h3= options.title
      p= options.description
      div.buttons
        each val in options.buttons
          a(href= val.link, target="_blank")
            img(class= val.className, src= assets + "img/stores/" + val.image)
```

Comment: I don't have this project anymore but I tested with a smaller example (and maybe easier to read here) and it works. Passing the object is the solution. Thanks ;) https://codepen.io/joaosaro/pen/jeWgWd